# Trying to display all posts in given category - getting error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building my first laravel app.

I'm trying to display all posts in x category.

My routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/{id}/{slug?}', 'PostsController@show')->name('show');
Route::get('/categories/{category}', 'CategoriesController@index')->name('category');
```

My category model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

My category controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Category;

class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Category $category)
    {
        $posts = $category->posts;

        return view('index', compact('posts'));
    }
}
```

Getting: "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Works if I change:

```
Route::get('/{id}/{slug?}', 'PostsController@show')->name('show');
```

To:

```
Route::get('/{post}', 'PostsController@show')->name('show');
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route `/{id}/{slug?}` regex is capturing the word `categories` of your other route and preventing it to work as expected. You have 2 options here:

- Move the `categories/{category}` up to the post route. Laravel routes stops on first match.
- Define what `{id}` can be

  ```
  Route::get('/{id}/{slug?}', 'PostsController@show')->name('show')->where('id', '[0-9]*');
  ```

Anyway, if that post id route is a backend route, I shall recommend to you to prefix it like `posts/{id}/{slug?}`. If it's a frontend, choose one of the previous solutions (or even both).

Comment: thanks a lot! Could you tell me more about how the `/{id}/{slug?}` regex was capturing the word categories from other route? And why defining an {id} just fixed that?

Comment: @wdotis the `{id}` is a regex placeholder, if you don't define it with `where`, is a regex like `.*`, in other words, match every single route. If you define the file with the where, you change that `.*` into `[0-9]*` which means only match numbers.

Comment: you're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's the route that's configured incorrectly, sometimes the order that you define the routes can cause issues.

try to define the routes in theis order instead to see if it makes a difference:

```
Route::get('/{id}/{slug?}', 'PostsController@show')->name('show');
Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/categories/{category}', 'CategoriesController@index')->name('category');
```

Answer (score 0):

İf you have many to many or one to many relationships between categories and posts, you can do that.

```
Route::get('categories/{category_slug?}',['as'=>'category.show','uses'=>'CategoriesController@Show'})
```

and in your controller;

```
 public function Show($category_slug){

        $category = Category::where('category_slug',$category_slug)->first();


        return view('index',compact('category'));
    }
```

and in your blade;

```
@foreach($category->posts as $post)
  $post->title
  $post->content
@endforeach
```